# application of entire function $f$ of order $\gamma$, $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ for polynomial case.

Tags: complex-analysis

First, Let me explain the definition

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is entire function, we say that $f$ is of finite order if 
\begin{align}
|f(z)| \leq \alpha e^{\beta|z|^{\gamma}}, \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}
\end{align} 
and the infimum of the exponents $\gamma$ is called the order of $f$.

Now consider $F$ as a polynomial, clearly 
\begin{align}
|F(z)| = |a_n z^n + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \cdots a_1 z + a_0| \leq \alpha e^{|z|^{\epsilon}}
\end{align}
so I see polynomial $f$ is finite order and its order is $0$.

Now I have following Lemma

> An entire function $f(z)$ of order $\gamma$ which does not have zeros can be written as $f(z) = e^{g(z)}$ where $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $\gamma$.

Now I have trouble. If i assume $f(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, then $\gamma=0$ implies $g(z) = C$ where $C$ is constant. Then $f(z) = e^C = D$ with $D$ is constant. But this is not ture.

Is something missing in the lemma?  The lemma above comes from lemma 8.1 "lectures on the riemann zeta function" by iwaniec.

Comment: "which does not have zeros" looks important. Any polynomial that is not constant has a zero (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me read the lemma again, An entire function f(z) of **order** $\gamma$ **which does not have zeros** can be written as $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$ where $g(z)$ is a **polynomial** of **degree** $\gamma$.

Note: The polynomial is of **degree** $\gamma$, it did not say that the polynomial is of **order** $\gamma$.

The **order** of a polynomial is **zero** but the **degree** of that polynomial may not be zero. Which was your primary confusion.

The time you assumed "*$f(z)$ be a polynomial of degree n...*" then the order of that polynomial is zero but you avoided the fact that **it has zeros inside $\Bbb C$** [due to Fundamental theorem of algebra]. But the lemma holds for those functions which have **no zeros**.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!